# Meaning of "positive" mane?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading "Journey to the Centre of the Earth" by Jules Verne.

In chapter 39: "Man Alive", I came across the following:

> His head, which was as big as a buffalo's was half hidden in the tangled growth of his unkempt hair - a **positive mane**, like that of the primitive elephant.

I want to know the meaning of "positive" mane. The author in an earlier chapter also used it as following:

> positive roar; positive statements; positive pleasure; positive whirlpool; positive deluge
> (In later chapters as:) positive rout; positively disgraceful

Please help.

Comment: Intensifier ***positive*** as cited is a stylised / literary usage, in a context where most people would have used ***real***. Compare *She [prepared a **real feast** for](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22prepared+a+real+feast+for%22) the guests* (dozens of hits in Google Books) and *She [prepared a **positive feast** for](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22prepared+a+positive+feast+for%22) the guests* (no recorded instances in Google Books).

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks a lot! That's quite an accurate and a succinct replacement.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to *denigrate* your cited translator's choice of intensifier (it's perfectly "acceptable", just not necessarily the "best" choice). But if you *do* want to emulate this stylised / literary usage yourself, it's worth noting the far more common choice: *She [prepared a **veritable** feast for](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22prepared+a+veritable+feast+for%22) the guests* (again, *dozens* of hits in Google Books).

Comment: @FumbleFingers sure, thanks a lot for the kind advice. But I guess it wouldn't fit with veritable whirlpool and likes, isn't it?

Comment: As @WeatherVane says, perhaps your translator just likes the word "positive". Personally I don't see much point in using ***positive[ly]*** to intensify referents like ***whirlpool, disgraceful*** anyway. Nobody ever says anything is ***veritably disgraceful*** - but apart from that "adverbial" context, you should probably stick with ***real*** (for all "natural" contexts - but consider ***veritable*** for "stylised" contexts).

Comment: @FumbleFingers got it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Cambridge has for [positive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/positive)

> certain and without any doubt.

So his hair wasn't just long, but ... [like an animal's hair].
It is typically used for emphasis, e.g.

> It wasn't just a lucky find: it was a positive gold mine!

The usage here is similar to one use of 'very'

> This is the very thing I was looking for.

Also see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/positive)

> **2c** (2) UNQUALIFIED *a positive disgrace*.

Jules Verne wrote in French. It is reckoned that some of the translations were [not very good](https://www.motaword.com/blog/jules-verne). Perhaps the translator liked that particular "turn of phrase".

You could go back to the French to find out what adjectives Verne used.

---

Edit: [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/4791/pg4791.html) shows the original French to be

> *On eût dit une **véritable** crinière*

FWIW Google Translate gives that as

> It looked like a **real** mane

Remember too that your translation may have been 19th century English usage.

Comment: Thank you, +1, after speculating a bit more, your answer is making more sense as time is passing as apart from the translation issues which might be the case, but otherwise also, a scientist again and again saying "positive" might be related to their profession where confirmation is needed explicitly in their statements (and this is a far cry in thinking but maybe to reflect that they are sober while making the statement?).

Comment: @InanimateBeing: it does not have that connotation for this native English speaker. Indeed, somewhat the reverse, because using "positive" in this way suggests a strongly subjective evaluation, which is the converse of what is (stereotypically) appropriate to a scientist.

Comment: It's a bit old-fashioned but it's not a wrong translation, just a particular usage of positive. (You sometimes see "véritable" translated as "veritable" which is much worse!)

Comment: @StuartF, a different view point. Appreciated. Thanks a lot!